# Collaborative question/answer plugin for WordPress

Tags: plugin-recommendation, design, forum, wiki, stackoverflow

I am looking for a collaborative question/answer plugin built in the same sort of style as StackOverflow.

Features I am looking for:

- Profiles
- Index of questions with search by tag/title/contents
- Vote up/down
- Edit yours and other peoples questions+answers (wiki style)
- Integrated markdown (or similar)

Before you ask, yes I have seen [Question and Answer Forum Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/question-and-answer-forum/) and [WP-Answers](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-answers/) but neither have support for collaborative editing.

Comment: Is it absolutely essential that this is a WP plugin, or would a stand-alone PHP app that can work alongside WP be sufficient?

Comment: Well I'd rather not, but what's available?

Comment: @PaulGregory for me, and maybe the OP, that would be acceptable as long as seamless integration was possible - i.e. no secondary login.

Comment: hi dunc, I revised the question to allow an answer of standalone PHP based as long as auth was fully integrated at a cookie level

Answer (score 6):

Templatic has one called [Q&A WordPress](http://templatic.com/cms-themes/answers/). Here is the [demo](http://templatic.com/demos/?theme=answers).

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for something StackOverflow style, with Up/Down votes and collaborative wiki-style editing.

Comment: Take another look at the demo, it has all of those features and looks almost identical to StackOverflow.

Comment: This is - yet another - excellent **theme** that can be used for Q&A-style WordPress websites. However, it is an entire site-wide theme and I suspect, like others, that it amends the existing WordPress database structure. Unfortunately for me this means these themes are no good, though it might be good for the OP. +1.

Answer (score 2):

WPMU's [Q&A plugin](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin) has almost all the functionality you're looking for -- it uses HTML instead of Markdown.  The admin panel lets you assign various capabilities to different roles, including the ability to edit others' questions and answers.

Comment: It didn't integrate with my theme... so I uninstalled it. It doesn't actually uninstall, and I can't report the bug without paying a subscription. FOOOO

Comment: this is one terrible plugin. It did not work in my site. There is no way you can post question in free version. There is no register link in order to ask question. You can not post a comment on a question. this makes it pretty useless and not like stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Q&A Lite](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qa/) plugin. I could not find it by search on my site plugin install, but downloading the zip and uploading in the admin helped.